# Is there an updated version of the iPad's checklist app which allows sub items

Tags: ipad, applications

i have never seen any of the stock apps say they have an update and i kinda think the checklist app on the ipad is lacking cause it does not allow an item to have sub items which, when all checked, the parent items is checked, here's are some of examples of what i mean by sub items

common shopping list example:

> you have 2 items in a list, Cake and Topping, Cake would list all the stuff you need to buy to make the cake's base while topping would include the icing and what kind of decorations you need to buy

My Example 1: series marathon list

> I have 1 item called .Hack which would have sub items that list all the games and anime for that series, the .Hack item should not be checked unless i have checked every sub item of it

My Example 2: System Component purchases List

> i have an item called Epitpah which in it has the following
>
> - 4 items named "HDMI Switch"
> - 12 items named "HDMI Cable"
> - 2 items named "AV -> HDMI Converter"
> - 1 item named "Wii -> HDMI adaptor"
> - an item named "Level 1 Setup" which contains the following
> - - an item named "HDMI Switch Connected"
> - - an item named "Level 2 Setup" which contains the following
> - - - an item named "Level 2 connected to point 1-1"
> - - - an item named "Alcaid Connected to point 2-1 via AV -> HDMI Converter"
> - - - an item named "Ryoko Connected to point 2-2 via AV -> HDMI Converter"

now i'm wondering if there's an updated version of the checklist app for the ipad that apple has put up as a separate app of if there is a third party app that works like an upgraded version of the checklist app

Answer (score 1):

[OmniOutliner](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnioutliner-ipad/) does this sort of thing, and more, but I don't believe the stock apps on the device even come close to accommodating sub-items. The Reminders' app is very limited in functionality, and it is the closest thing to a stock app that handles lists.